# Обладают ли "памятью" boost::regex ? (очередной косяк embracadero rad studio ?)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, boost, c++

Мне надо "прогнать" строчку на регулярных выражениях. 
Для этого я написал функцию, которая прогоняет отдельно взятую функцию на отдельно взятой строчке:

```
   UnicodeString findSubString(UnicodeString regex,const UnicodeString inPut, int outPutIndex)
{
    static const boost::wregex reg(regex.w_str());
    std::wstring chat_input(inPut.w_str());
    boost::match_results<std::wstring::const_iterator> results;

    if (boost::regex_match(chat_input, results, reg))
         return std::wstring(results[outPutIndex]).c_str();
}
```

**Суть проблемы:**
Когда я вызываю данную функцию на массиве из регулярных выражений, то он каждый раз проверяет строчку только на том регулярном выражении, которое в него вошло первым. Т.е. все остальные передаваемые регулярные выражения игнорируются.

Ставил точку остановки в начале функции. В параметры передается все верно-новое регулярное выражение.

**Решение проблемы, которое не устраивает:**
Если я хочу прогнать строчку на 2-х регулярных выражениях,  выходом служит способ создать 2 функции с разными именами, но одинаковым кодом. В первое передавать первое выражение, а во второе второе. Но данное решение меня не устраивает, т.е. количество регулярных выражений может рости, а создавать много повторяющегося кода-ужасно.

---

Скажите пожалуйста, что это может быть и почему?? Как с этим бороться?
Я  даже не понимаю, как может быть возможно подобное поведение, т.к. вызов двух функций у которых различны лишь имена- приводят к одному и тому же результату.

используемая среда rad studio.

Comment: Уберите модификатор `static` у локальной переменной.

Comment: какой громкий заголовок

Answer (score 8):

Вы сами создали проблему - она в коде просто выпирает - Ключевые слова "static const". Благодаря слову static, инициализация происходит один раз. Все вызовы этой функции формально пропускают эту строку и не делают инициализацию. Вам там не static, ни const не нужен.

Вот так и появляются легенды о "косяках студии".

Comment: Не знаю, хорошо это или плохо, но в Си такая ошибка невозможна. 

Компилятор позволяет инициализировать статические переменные только константными выражениями (т.е. на вызов функции заругается).

Comment: @avp: а указатель?

Comment: И указатели тоже. По сути, например, в


    int main (int, char **);
    
    int f ()
    {
      int aa;
      static int *pa = &aa;
      static void *pm = main, *pm2 = pm, *ppa = &pa;
    }


main это константа (времени загрузки программы в память (не уверен, что это общепринятый термин, но IMHO суть понятна)).

`pm` инициализируется, `ppa` тоже, а вот с `pm2` и `pa` будут ошибки 

    error: initializer element is not constant